# Does Avalonia.UI support MessageBox?

Tags: .net-core, avaloniaui

I am working with Avalonia.UI and .NetCore.
What is (is there) an Avalonia.UI equivalent of the System.Windows.MessageBoxResults?

In my initial investigation, it doesn't look like Avalonia supports the MessageBox directly.
I found MessageBox.Avalonia, which exposes an enum type for MessageBoxResult.
However, when attempting to use it I get a

> Argument type ... is not CLS-compliant

1) Is there an Avalonia.UI equivalent?
2) If I use the MessageBox.Avalonis library, what is the fix for the "not Compliant" errors?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: “Argument type ... is not CLS-compliant” is not even an error. Why do you set your own project to be CLS compliant? That's not needed in most cases, so set it to false please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.clscompliantattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Lex - OK, Thankyou